# Can't get ffmpeg to generate an MP4 file on iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I'm having serious problems trying to get an iOS app to create an MP4 file from an RTSP stream using ffmpeg.

I can open the stream, decode it, show the video on screen and play the live audio without any issues. The problems arise when I try to output the AV stream to a file.

If I ask ffmpeg to create an MP4 file, it fails, informing me that the audio codec in the stream is incompatible with MP4 files. If I attempt to transcode the audio into acc, then ffmpeg lets me continue, but during the file output I get multiple "aac bitstream error" messages, and the recording is silent.

I also tried having ffmpeg create a mov (Quicktime) file instead of MP4. If I do that, it seems to work: I get a mov file that plays back with audio. That being done, I tried to transcode the mov file to mp4 using AVAssetExportSession. But this doesn't work: it reports that the decode failed.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: You're trying to do something completely non-standard, and you showed no code. It's not possible to help you, although I'd like to...

Comment: I thought it was pretty standard to be able to take a stream and write it out to a file. I see people doing this all the time with the command-line version of ffmpeg.

Comment: As for my code, it is some 700+ lines of me trying stuff, pasting in stuff from examples, etc. The question boils down to the fact that I'm getting this message: "aac bitstream error". I need to know what causes that message. Someone wrote that code; someone added that message. That someone, or someone else who has seen that code, should be able to tell me precisely what triggers it. Or if not that, at least where I can find it in the ffmpeg source to see for myself. I've searched for the error message, but come up empty.